# Google map does not load it is giving me authorization error but i have checked the key and it is correct

Tags: android, google-maps

08-09 01:34:43.484  18065-18267/com.ovent.eventapp E/b﹕ Authentication failed on the server.

08-09 01:34:43.484  18065-18267/com.ovent.eventapp E/Google Maps Android API﹕ Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.

08-09 01:34:43.495  18065-18267/com.ovent.eventapp E/Google Maps Android API﹕ In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)

```
Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.

Ensure that the following Android Key exists:

API Key: AIzaSyC9052Ao1HRmCiJ13uYYdKae-UpAAClyQg
```

Comment: are you using the same debug.keystore which was used to generate the Google Maps API key ?

Comment: yes. I have created a google maps activity and followed the steps given in google_maps_api.xml file. But it still give me authorization error.

Comment: what I am asking is, when registering for Maps API key, we have to provide SHA fingerprint which is different for different machines. So if you have used other SHA fingerprint and registered key with it. You have to get the debug.keystore file and replace it with yours

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to enable the api from google developer console. 
[image]